# How to mark a git branch as merged?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I know this sounds a little weird, but sometimes manually editing is more convenient than merging and resolving conflicts. I would like GitHub/GitLab to show a `merged` label on the branches I manually "merged". Can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way you can do this is to actually do a `git merge`, but use the `-s ours` merge strategy to ignore any actual contribution from the branch. From the [git merge documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-ours):

> #### ours
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the *recursive* merge strategy.

This would be suitable to use after you have manually edited a branch to "merge" it, but then want to inform Git that the branch has in fact been logically merged.

Comment: Interesting, but this added the lot of commits to the target branch after I had squash-merged the source. It can make your history confusing, getting all the commits after the one that actually made the change!

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This works only if you have a pull request open for that branch.**

You'll have to do a fast-forward merge:

```
(master)$ git merge <your-branch> --no-ff
(master)$ git push origin master
```

Now your branch should be labeled as `merged`. I don't think it will work without the creation of a pull request at least for GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in VSCode after:

1. Selecting "merge main into current branch"
2. Solving the extensive merge conflicts that required editing files other than just the ones showing conflicts
3. Staging everything, including those extra file edits
4. Committing and pushing

GitHub interpreted the merge commit as a regular commit and showed all lines from the merge as part of my pull request.

Undoing the merge commit and trying again, `git merge` didn't seem to make sense because I was already in the middle of a merge.

The easiest solution was to:

1. Stash everything from the messy merge commit
2. Start a "merge main into current branch" again
3. Select "discard all changes"
4. Pop/apply the stash
5. Commit

After that, it showed up like a real merge commit in GitHub as desired.